# How do i check that the email is valid

Tags: php, validation

How can I validate an email and also add fade in effects to my existing code ?

```
<?php
if ($_POST['submit']) { 
if ($name != '' && $email != '') { 
if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) {    
echo '<div style="border: 1px solid #00EE00; padding: 10px;"><p>Your message has been sent to our Customer Care Team.</p></div>';    } else {    
echo ' <div style="border: 1px solid #FF030D; padding: 10px;"><p>Something went wrong, go back and try again!</p></div> ';   }  } 
else if ($_POST['submit'] ) {    
echo '<div style="border: 1px solid #FF030D; padding: 10px;"> <p>You need to fill in all required fields!!</p></div>'; } }
?>
```

Comment: What does jQuery have to do with your PHP code?

Comment: PS I am a newbie at this stuff

Comment: It was in the suggested tags

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can valid email address Using [`FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL`](http://www.w3schools.com/php/filter_validate_email.asp)

```
if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
     echo "E-mail is not valid";
} else {
      // your code
}
```

You can Implement it in your code like...

```
<?php
if ($_POST['submit']) { 
    if ($name != '' && $email != '') { 
        if(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) {    
                echo '<div style="border: 1px solid #00EE00; padding: 10px;"><p>Your message has been sent to our Customer Care Team.</p></div>';
            } else {    
                echo ' <div style="border: 1px solid #FF030D; padding: 10px;"><p>Something went wrong, go back and try again!</p></div> ';
            }
        }
        else
        {
            echo '<div style="border: 1px solid #FF030D; padding: 10px;"> <p>Invalid Email Address</p></div>';
        }
    } 
    else{    
        echo '<div style="border: 1px solid #FF030D; padding: 10px;"> <p>You need to fill in all required fields!!</p></div>'; 
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: How would that look with my code and how would I face the responses in ?

Comment: @WebDeveloper He has taken you 99% of the way there. Surely you can figure out how to integrate this check into your code.

Comment: I have and thank ever so much for your help, every little helps :-)

Comment: @WebDeveloper check my updated answer, hope it will help you...

Comment: @SumitBijvani Most of the time your answer is always valid :)

Comment: @chintankhetiya and most of the time you do very well than me :D